# Memory issues in string reversal program

Tags: c, pointers, memory

So I am trying to write a C program that takes in a string from the command line, and traverses the string and reverses it using a linked list. It isn't currently workikng and I'm not sure why. I have only programmed in C++ up until now, so the minor differences in C are really throwing me for a loop. Can someone help me find the errors in my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct st_CharNode 
{
char theChar;
struct st_CharNode *next;
} CharNode;


void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer );


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
char *stringBuffer;

//  Check number of user supplied arguments.  
if( argc != 2 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s string.  This reverses the string "
             "given on the command line\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

// Copy the argument so we can make changes to it
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1]) );
strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );

// Reverse the string
reverseIt( stringBuffer );

// Print the reversed string
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", *stringBuffer );

return 0;
}


// Build a linked list backwards, then traverse it.

void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer )
{
CharNode *head, *node;
char *scan, *stop;

// initialize local vars
head = node = NULL;

// find the start and end of the string so we can walk it
scan = stringbuffer;
stop = stringbuffer + strlen(stringbuffer) + 1;

// walk the string
while (scan < stop)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        head->theChar = *scan;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        node->theChar = *scan;
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    scan++;
}

// Re-point to the buffer so we can drop the characters
scan = stringbuffer;

//  Traverse the nodes and add them to the string
while( head != NULL )
{
    *scan = head->theChar;
    free( head );
    node = head->next;
    head = node;
    scan++;
}

// Release head
free( head );   
}
```

My current output when I ./a.out and enter a string like "Hello" on the command line is "the reversed string is '(null)'".

Comment: I assume the use of the linked list for this case is some instructor's sadistic way to make sure you are not having any fun tonight... one would never use such a convoluted method to address such a simple problem "in real life".

Comment: Right off the bat, your allocated string length for your copy is not correct. It is one element short. You failed to account for the terminating nulchar. Also, your string copy is in the wrong direction if you want to make a copy of `argv[1]`. You're copying indeterminate data from your new allocation *and overwriting `argv[1]` in the process* by doing this: `strcpy(argv[1], stringBuffer);`

Comment: Do you mean on this part: strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );? If so, would I just make is stringBuffer + 1?

Comment: And if you paid attention to your compiler warnings (please, always turn on ALL warnings!) you would notice that in line 34 you are looking at `*stringBuffer`, but treating it as a pointer to a string. Since you are pointing at the terminating character, you get `(null)` back. Don't include the null character in the copy, add a '\0' at the end of your reversed string, and `printf("reversed string is %s\n", stringBuffer);` - and you will get a long way there.

Answer (score 2):

Just to name a few of the problems...

**Undersized Allocation**

You're failing to account for the terminating nulchar required for a C-string.

This:

```
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1]) );
```

Should be this:

```
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
```

---

**Wrong Copy Direction**

Immediately after your allocation, you're copying uninitialized data from your new buffer, blasting over the top of `argv[1]` until a nulchar is detected. More undefined behavior.

This:

```
strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );
```

Should be this:

```
strcpy( stringBuffer, argv[1] );
```

---

**Incorrect Dereference Passed to Printf**

The `"%s"` format specifier requires an *address* of a nulchar-terminated string be passed as the matching variadic parameter. You're passing `*stringBuffer`, i.e. a character value, promoted to an `int` by the compiler, then used as an address. Worse, because it is a variadic function, this is perfectly legal to *code*, but obviously undefined behavior to *run*. A good code-static-analyzing compiler will catch this for you.

This:

```
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", *stringBuffer );
```

Should be this:

```
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", stringBuffer );
```

---

And all of that is without even going into the actual reversal function. Fix at least these. You don't need to (and in fact would be crazy to) use a linked list to reverse a C-string. it can be done with two pointers and a single loop (or one pointer and an index), so dissecting that function seems counterproductive. Reversing a string is literally this simple (and in place):

```
void reverse_str(char *str)
{
    if (!str || !*str || !*(str+1))
        return;

    char *rhs = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (str < rhs)
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *rhs;
        *rhs-- = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer as usual. Just a day or two and you will hit the magical 20 k milestone! Here's 10 to help you along...

Answer (score 2):

The biggest mistake is in the line

```
strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );
```

The syntax is

```
strcpy( char* destination, char* source );
```

You obviously have the two reversed.

You also need to make sure you stop before you get to the nul character - you do this by setting the `stop` variable to a value that is one less than you are currently doing:

```
stop = stringbuffer + strlen(stringbuffer) ;
```

And when you print the string out, you need to give the `printf` function the right parameter (a pointer to a string):

```
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", stringBuffer );
```

Finally - thanks to @WhozCraig - you need to allocate more memory to the buffer to account for the terminating `'\0':

```
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1])) + 1 );
```

Putting it all together, the following is working code (included a few debug printf statements along the way - always a good idea while you are trying to figure out what is going on:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct st_CharNode
{
char theChar; 
struct st_CharNode *next;
} CharNode;


void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer );


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
char *stringBuffer;

//  Check number of user supplied arguments.
if( argc != 2 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s string.  This reverses the string "
             "given on the command line\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

// Copy the argument so we can make changes to it
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1]) + 1 );
strcpy( stringBuffer, argv[1]);

// Reverse the string
reverseIt( stringBuffer );

// Print the reversed string
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", stringBuffer );

return 0;
}   

// Build a linked list backwards, then traverse it.

void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer )
{
CharNode *head, *node;
char *scan, *stop;

// initialize local vars
head = node = NULL;
printf("reversing '%s'\n", stringbuffer);

// find the start and end of the string so we can walk it
scan = stringbuffer;
stop = stringbuffer + strlen(stringbuffer) ;

// walk the string
while (scan < stop)
{
    printf("character: %c\n", *scan);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        head->theChar = *scan;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        node->theChar = *scan;
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    scan++;
}

// Re-point to the buffer so we can drop the characters
scan = stringbuffer;
printf("==== now reversing:====\n");
//  Traverse the nodes and add them to the string
while( head != NULL )
{
    *scan = head->theChar;
    printf("character: %c\n", *scan);
    free( head );
    node = head->next;
    head = node;
    scan++;
}
*stop = 0; // add the terminating nul
// Release head
free( head );
}
```

Comment: yours is actually better. at least you took the time to cover the reversal function. I just didn't see the point. and +1.

Comment: Thank you - and I have included your improvement now.